# json_decode returns "NULL" and I don't know why

Tags: php, json

When I write this:

```
<?php    
  $social = ControladorPlantilla::ctrEstiloPlantilla();    
  var_dump($social["redesSociales"]);    
?>
```

Everything is fine, but when I do this:

```
<?php    
  $social = ControladorPlantilla::ctrEstiloPlantilla();
  var_dump(json_decode($social["redesSociales"],true));
?>
```

It returns `NULL`.

What can I do?

Comment: What does `var_dump($social["redesSociales"]);` display?

Comment: NULL is returned from json_decode when json string cannot be decoded so it is probably not a valid json string. As @NigelRen wrote, provide us the `$social["redesSociales"]` contents

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples, the provided input and the expected output) in order to get a (useful) answer. Before posting a question, [search](/search) the site and make sure a similar question wasn't already answered. Show what you have tried and where you got stuck to maximize the chances to get help.

Comment: There is a simple explanation, the value of `$social["redesSociales"]` is not valid [JSON](https://json.org). Put into the question the value of `$social["redesSociales"]` if it is short or put it somewhere on the web and post a link to it. In its current status your question cannot be answered and will be closed. You can, of course, re-open it after you add the data.

Comment: Can you tell us what you get as a response when you execute the first script? If `$social["redesSociales"]` is not a valid JSON string, the `json_decode()` function returns `NULL`. See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-returnvalues)

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble with the data base!

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can try following at first, so you can find out all of things inside.

```
var_dump(json_decode([ "social" => $social ], true));
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Understood.. This could check the $social is valid or invalid? And to check the item existency and validity. I hope this could helps. And bautista will make proper additional correction with his question. Cheers.